# Parsing using Dom produces type mismatch

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, reflection

Given the following code , under Eclipse , I get a type mismatch error  :

```
package xmlInterface;


import javax.swing.text.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import gameManage.round;

import java.io.File;

import javax.lang.model.element.Element;

import javax.swing.text.Segment;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.classfile.Method;







        public void writeToXml(round[] games) throws ParserConfigurationException
        {


                       int i;
                // build a doucument by the parser
                       DocumentBuilderFactory document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                       DocumentBuilder docBuilder = document.newDocumentBuilder();

                       Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
                       Element rootElement = doc.createElement("GameOut");
...
...
...
}
```

I get the following error in Eclipse :

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from org.w3c.dom.Element to javax.lang.model.element.Element
```

Can anyone please explain how can I fix this ?

Thank you 
Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've mistaken an import. Not

```
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
```

but

```
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
```

Don't use import with * like

```
org.w3c.dom.*
```

otherwise you'd be likely to get some "hiding" error, since the last "Element" import you've coded (javax.lang.model.element.Element) will hide the org.w3c.dom.Element included in the import org.w3c.dom.* line.